# Remove iframe before load page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

How do I remove an iframe before a page loads?

On my website I have users fill out a surveymonkey survey in an iframe. Upon completion of the survey, surveymonkey redirects to a page in my website domain. This new page is still trapped within the iframe; I want the iframe removed before this new page is loaded. I tried the following code, but this removes both the iframe AND the content of this new page I want loaded, producing a blank screen:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('iframe', parent.document).remove();
});
</script>
</head>
</html>
<?php
//the content for the page I want loaded
?>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: http://usablelayout.com/articles/automatically-break-out-iframe

Comment: Sounds like you essentially want a framebuster: `if(top != self) top.location.replace(location);`

Answer (score 0):

*Cleaning up unanswered questions*

You want a framebuster

> if(top != self) top.location.replace(location);